# unexpected top level exception-Android studio Inspite of no duplicates

Tags: android

i know this question has been answered a many times,i tried all ways bt not working for me at all. I refered a lib in android studio,build the project and am getting the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\manalim\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\dx.bat --dex --output E:\MigrationFromEclTostudio\app\build\libs\app-debug.dex E:\MigrationFromEclTostudio\app\build\classes\debug E:\MigrationFromEclTostudio\app\build\dependency-cache\debug E:\MigrationFromEclTostudio\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\classes-9f889413450cab598adf7f9e7fbc4b615d2af144.jar E:\MigrationFromEclTostudio\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\google-play-services-cbe976cd78aae99b019ba10bdd87d55acb9949b6.jar E:\MigrationFromEclTostudio\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\simple-xml-2.6.1-07b87981e87a36154f3c945922849669a8a391c7.jar E:\MigrationFromEclTostudio\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.0.1-94b91e1fee2be61286a1fe04c97fca852e863a63.jar
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)





below is the build.gradle:

**apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/simple-xml-2.6.1.jar')
}
**

build.gradle for app:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'

    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

thats it..help would be really appreciated as am working oj it since a very long time..

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: i guess the error is at this line :Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode ...but i dont understand the meaning of it..

Answer (score 3):

```
Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode
```

Try removing com.google.admobsdk-googleplay or similar if you already have it, it seems like another plugin is already including the need libraries.

Comment: Actually, I delete google-play-services.jar from libs folder. In my build.gradle file, already have line "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'".

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remove this line:

```
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

and to delete the corresponding jar from the lib folder. This is not necessary any more because of this line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Also note that you should generally not put a + there but rather maintain a fixed version number to ensure your app's stability.

E.g.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```